# Mimic Salesforce Maintenance Popup

Tags: visualforce

Does anyone know how to mimic the pop-up that Salesforce uses for their Maintenance pop-ups? I'd like to have that same look and feel but customize it.

Comment: Which popup is that? You have an image? IIRC the maintenance notification is not a popup rather a page in itself...